# Inner Join with where clause using SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my query

```
Select c.payment_method, c.device_type, jo.delivery_type
from commercial c inner join 
     operation jo
     on c.sno = jo.sno  
where payment_method = 'Cyber Source';
```

When I execute the program, it show me only the column name

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/ create your table with data and show us your try so that we can get better insight why not working

Comment: Please give more detail. I think it's hard to understand the problem.

Comment: My guess is that you are getting no rows because either the `JOIN` or the `WHERE` has no matches.

Comment: Show us your code please..

Comment: Show some table data and be more speific

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific. If you're saying that the query displays only the column names, it means no records satisfy either the join condition or filter condition.

Answer (score 0):

First check your database both  table that have matched column  value in both table.
If all checking are done look at you database table and find your selected field contain real data  and relation must match at least one value.

Hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

The business question is: Orders with "Cyber Source" as Payment Method. Need to breakdown by device type and delivery type

have 2 tables
Commercial - sno, unit_price, revenue, discount, payment method, device type
Operation - sno, delivery type, product weight.

Primary Key will be sno. updated query

select Device_Type, Delivery_Type,count(*) as Number_Total

from commercial c

inner join operation o

on c.sno = o.sno

where Payment_Method = 'cybersource'

group by Device_Type, delivery_type

order by Number_Total